# (let (next (f guess)) vs (let ((next (f guess)))

Tags: syntax, scheme, lisp, let, sicp

The fix-point practice in sicp

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme
(define tolerance 0.00001)

(define (fixed-point f first-guess)
  (define (close-enough? v1 v2)
    (< (abs (- v1 v2)) tolerance))
  (define (try guess)
    (let ((next (f guess)))
      (if (close-enough? guess next)
          next
          (try next))))
  (try first-guess))
(fixed-point cos 1.0)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 0.7390822985224024
```

Reference the line

```
(let ((next (f guess)))
```

I assumed that extra parenthesis are added, and changed it to

```
(let (next (f guess))
```

run it again but refuse to work

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme
(define tolerance 0.00001)

(define (fixed-point f first-guess)
  (define (close-enough? v1 v2)
    (< (abs (- v1 v2)) tolerance))
  (define (try guess)
    (let (next (f guess))
      (if (close-enough? guess next)
          next
          (try next))))
  (try first-guess))
(fixed-point cos 1.0)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

What's the problem?

Comment: "I assumed that extra parenthesis are added". Nope, you should never assume that the code in the book has more (or less) parentheses than needed. If necessary check the documentation page for each special form used, to clarify the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of syntax, you should check the documentation for [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html). It expects a *list* of bindings and a body, where each biding is a list with two elements, a variable name and an expression - so this is the correct way (added extra line breaks for explanation, but you should never indent like this):

```
(let ( ; start list of bindings
      ( ; start binding
       next ; binding name
       (f guess) ; binding value
      ) ; end binding
     ) ; end list of bindings
  <body>)
```

Your attempt failed:

```
(let (next (f guess))
  ...)
```

... Because it's missing the outer `()` that delimit the list of bindings, before the body part. It should be obvious by now that we can have multiple bindings as part of a `let`, that's why the outer `()` for the list of bindings are mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

**Scheme**

> I assumed that extra parenthesis are added

in Scheme one can't assume that. Often parentheses are not optional, but a necessary part of the expression syntax.

The syntax for `let` in Scheme (R5RS, R6RS, R7RS) is:

```
(let <bindings> <body>) 

Syntax: <Bindings> should have the form

((<variable1> <init1>) ...)
```

Thus in your example `next` is the variable and `(f guess)` is the init form.

Your attempt to omit a level of parentheses resulted in a syntax error. The following form is not valid Scheme.

```
(let (next          ;  a symbol is not allowed, only (var init) lists
      (f guess))    ;  variable 'f' and init form 'guess'
  ...
  )
```

The syntax is slightly different from some other Lisp languages.

**Emacs Lisp**

See for example Emacs Lisp: [3.6.1 The Parts of a let Expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Parts-of-let-Expression.html).

Thus in Emacs Lisp it is possible to write just a variable, so that it will be bound to `nil`:

```
(let ((var1 init1)
      var2
      (var3 init3)
      var4
      ...)
  ...)
```

**Common Lisp**

Common Lisp allows also to omit the init form. The syntax:

```
let ({var | (var [init-form])}*) declaration* form*
```

Thus in Common Lisp we can also have

```
CL-USER > (let ((a 10)     ; a bound to 10
                b          ; b bound to NIL 
                (c))       ; c bound to NIL
            (list a b c))
(10 NIL NIL)
```

But not in standard Scheme...

Comment: IOW in Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp `(let (next (f guess)) ...` == `(let ((next NIL) (f guess)) ...` has two bindings, for `next` and `f`.